# size of scripts(external links) + merging them into 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, gulp

when I download angular.js and upload it to my webhosting like so:

```
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
```

it has **141kb**. If I use original cdn:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
```

**Chrome**'s console shows is has size **just 45kb**. How is it possible? It's same code. This is happening to every other library of framework like jQuery or e.g. angular-material.

I have like 15 scripts so I wanted to merge them into 1 file and minify it(using gulp). But actually the result's size if 2x bigger than using cdn's(or external links). Huh? It's kinda confusing.

I tried **firefox** and it's showing size **122kb** so it might be just something with chrome. What should I do then? Just stop caring about chrome and merge it all using gulp?

Edit:
from the angular.js faq:

> How big is the angular.js file that I need to include?
>   The size of the file is ~50KB compressed and minified.

Comment: Download the CDN file to your system. Then compare the file sizes on disk. That will be a better comparison factor than comparing them in the browser.

Comment: If I download it from cdn it has 140kb. I'm comparing that size with cdn (chrome console)size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's all about gzip compression. Probably you have that option turned off on your server.

Are you using apache? Try something like

```
    <ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
    </ifModule>
```

(somwhere from google).

Comment: I'm not sure because if I open it in firefox it has also size 120kb. And I run this test http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php and it show's me my site is using gzip.

Comment: For chrome: ctrl+shift+j => Network => <Select_file> => Headers
(There should be "Content-Encoding:gzip" in "Response headers" if it's on and works correctly for needed file)

Comment: Oh, and you need to be sure to wipe it from cache first (ctrl+shift+r) to see if this header is present.

Comment: you are right, on my script's it's not there. I added this into .htaccess <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch> but I don't see any result

Comment: I'm not sure, if you're doing it right. Edited answer.

Comment: I tried also your code but there's still no content encoding in file

Comment: Well, can't help you anymore. Try checking if mod_gzip is really present and turned on on your server. It's probably not.

Comment: well it is: gzip compression enabled (phpinfo())